# How to call columns implicitly in certain R functions

Tags: r, tidyverse

There are some functions in R where you have to call columns explicitly by name, such as `pmin`. My question is how to get around this, preferably using `tidyverse`.

Here's some sample data.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(a = c(1:5), 
             b = c(6:10), 
             d = c(11:15), 
             e = c(16:20))

# A tibble: 5 x 4
      a     b     d     e
  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     6    11    16
2     2     7    12    17
3     3     8    13    18
4     4     9    14    19
5     5    10    15    20
```

Now I'd like to find the minimum of all the columns except for "e". I can do this:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(min = pmin(a, b, d))

# A tibble: 5 x 5
      a     b     d     e   min
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     6    11    16     1
2     2     7    12    17     2
3     3     8    13    18     3
4     4     9    14    19     4
5     5    10    15    20     5
```

But what if I have many columns and would like to call every column except "e" without having to type out each column's name? I've made several attempts but none successful. I used the column index in my examples but I'd prefer excluding "e" by name. See below.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(min = pmin(-e))

df %>% 
  mutate(min = pmin(names(. %>% select(.))[-4]))

df %>% 
  mutate(min = pmin(names(.)[-4]))

df %>% 
  mutate(min = pmin(noquote(paste0(names(.)[-4], collapse = ","))))

df %>% 
  mutate(min = pmin(!!ensyms(names(.)[-4])))
```

None of these worked and I'm a bit at a loss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option using `dplyr` and `purrr` could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(min = exec(pmin, !!!select(., -e)))

      a     b     d     e   min
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     6    11    16     1
2     2     7    12    17     2
3     3     8    13    18     3
4     4     9    14    19     4
5     5    10    15    20     5
```

For those not reading the comments, a nice option proposed by @IceCreamToucan and involving only `dplyr` could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(min = do.call(pmin, select(., -e)))
```

Comment: `mutate(min = invoke(pmin, select(., -e)))` also works

Comment: @IceCreamToucan true, however, I'm using `exec()` as `invoke()` is retired according to its documentation :)

Comment: huh, didn't notice, tx for the info. I guess you could also use `do.call` e.g. `mutate(min = do.call(pmin, select(., -e)))` but maybe less tidyverse-ish. I was thinking `!!!` might be innefficient, but if the only non-retired way to do this kind of thing in tidyverse is to use `!!!` that suggests my guess was probably wrong.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan you can definitely do that, it is even mentioned in the documentation for `exec()`. In this case, I decided to stick to pure `tidyverse` possibilities as the OP indicated such an interest :)

Comment: The `do.call` version is very nice, too. Thanks @IceCreamToucan.

Answer (score 3):

We can also use `reduce` with `pmin`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
   mutate(min = select(., -e) %>% 
                   reduce(pmin))
# A tibble: 5 x 5
#      a     b     d     e   min
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     6    11    16     1
#2     2     7    12    17     2
#3     3     8    13    18     3
#4     4     9    14    19     4
#5     5    10    15    20     5
```

---

Or with `syms` and `!!!`.  Note that `en`- prefix is used while using from inside a function

```
df %>% 
    mutate(min = pmin(!!! syms(names(.)[-4])))
# A tibble: 5 x 5
#      a     b     d     e   min
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     6    11    16     1
#2     2     7    12    17     2
#3     3     8    13    18     3
#4     4     9    14    19     4
#5     5    10    15    20     5
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I got close with the `syms` version. It seems like the !! and !!! notation changes with every update. I hope they settle on the notation soon. Or maybe I just think they keep changing it.

Comment: @hmhensen  The `!!` is for a single name character, `!!!` works for `>=1`

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by reshaping long, calculating the min by group, and then reshaping back to wide:

```
df %>% 
  rowid_to_column() %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(e, rowid)) %>% 
  group_by(rowid) %>% 
  mutate(min = min(value)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  pivot_wider() %>% 
  select(-rowid, -min, min)
```